# How to get Plain Text from HTML editor in ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit?

Tags: html, editor, ajaxcontroltoolkit, text-editor

How to get Plain Text from HTML editor in ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit?

`Editor1.Content` gives HTML text like

```
This is <span style=\"font-weight: bold\">BOLD</span> text
```

while i want plain text only

```
This is BOLD text
```

Comment: I would like to know how to do this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write this method in your code:

```
public static string GetTextonly(string editorcontent)
{
    string strtext = "";
    strtext = Regex.Replace(editorcontent, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
    return strtext;
}
```

after write this outside:

```
string plaintext = GetTextonly(txtMessage.Content);
```

you just add namespace for `System.Text.RegularExpression`